# Access video.js runtime properties in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am trying to print runtime properties of `Video.js` player in safari but  `hls`property is not coming. I am getting error saying `hls` is not defined.

***player.html***

```html
<body>
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.6.0/video.js"></script>
  <script src="videojs.hls.min.js"></script>

  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://manifest.us-west-2.qa2.boltdns.net/manifest/v1/hls/v4/clear/test/ddebe1d2-8285-46d6-9853-6bbc9f51616a/10s/master.m3u8?fastly_token=NTZkMDA5ZWRfNGI4NDYyMGE0YzZlODQyNDQ5OWI3NTdjNWI3NzQ5M2JkN2IyNjMxZDNhMWYzOTdlZTkwOGU2ZDFlNTk4YjQwYg%3D%3D"
             type="application/vnd.apple.mpegURL">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

<script>
var player = videojs('my-video', {
  hls: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});

player.play();

var bandwidth = player.hls.bandwidth;
 alert("Bandwidth" + bandwidth.toString());
</script>

</body>
```

I not getting why hls is not defined while I am getting `hls` on chrome and firefox.

Here is the error I am getting in safari console:[image]

Is there any other way to get runtime properties.

Comment: Maybe your issue is related to this one issue? https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/403

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, There is no way to control rendition switching on hls with safari because hls is done natively and safari (Quicktime in fact) does not expose any API to do that. You have to trust the browser to show the best possible quality.

More on it on [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) and on this [Github thread](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/issues/193)